# Modify SVG width from within R after export from plotly orca

Tags: r, svg, plotly, r-plotly

My goal is to save out an SVG file of a plotly graph, where the width argument is '100%' and static height is removed.

As it is, plotly orca (the tool for saving plotly objects) only supports specifying static pixel widths and heights.

The widths and heights set are important throughout the chart generation for maintaining proportions (It is an intricate plot combining many traces on both cartesian and polar co-ordinates).

This means the svg file saved is fixed width.

All processing has to occur within R. Is there a way to modify a text file from R commands? So far, my search has not yielded anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found my solution.

1. I am using `readLines()` to load my .svg file in to R.
2. Modify the offending style attribute using `gsub`. This works for me as the change I want to make is fixed and very simple.
3. I use `writeLines()` to over-write the old with the new.